# nasty Aggregation in SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, group-by, sqlplus, aggregation

nasty Aggregation in SQLPLUS

Hi All,
I have the next table:

```
   col.1   col.2
   2       1-V
   4       2-VV
   6       3-EC
   8       2-GD
   A       5-V
   C       2-EC
   E       2-GD
   10      6-V
   12      2-V
   14      1-GD
   14      1-V
```

what I need is to do some aggregation on the table and get something like the next table (group the row by col.2 using only the value that after '-' Like [V, VV, EC, GD]):

```
   Type    count
   EC      2
   GD      3
   V       5
   VV      1
```

I do not know how to use "GROUP BY" clause to do this task.

BR
Hosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem would be:

```
select regexp_replace(col_2, '^\d+-', null), count(1)
from the_next_table
group by regexp_replace(col_2, '^\d+-', null);
```

Enjoy.

PS: Of course, this solution is strongly dependent on the presumption that your `col.2` data are always of form `<some number><the dash symbol><anything>`. For such a case this solution strips away the `<some number><the dash symbol>` part and leaves only the `<anything>` for the aggregation.

Comment: @user3801158, then do not hesitate and accept or upvote the answers of your choice, so we get rewarded for spending our time answering you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  substr( "col2", instr( "col2", '-' )+1) as "type",
  count(*) as "count"
from table1
GROUP BY substr( "col2", instr( "col2", '-' )+1);
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70db1/3